# Is it possible to define concepts like free energy in the diffusion process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium, diffusion, non-equilibrium

How does the idea of free energy (which we derive from the canonical partition function) fit in the domain of non-equilibrium processes like diffusion?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, free energy is a thermodynamic potential originally defined for equilibrium processes. However, as with many concepts, physicists have proposed generalizations of the free energy to be able to describe non-equilibrium systems.

One nice introduction to the non-equilibrium free energy can be found in the article: Parrondo, J., Horowitz, J. & Sagawa, T. Thermodynamics of information. Nature Phys 11, 131–139 (2015). https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys3230

In the article, the free energy is defined by $F=<E>_{\rho} - TS(\rho)$, where rho is the density operator of the system (or the probability distribution of states if you consider classical statistical mechanics). This definition is very similar to the definition of equilibrium free energy, but with the important difference that the energy is not averaged over the Gibbs distribution (i.e. the thermal equilibrium distribution), but over an *arbitrary* distribution.

Importantly, the non-equilibrium free energy reaches its minimum for the equilibrium distribution. This corresponds to the intuition that non-equilibrium systems relax to equilibrium.

I hope this clarifies some of your doubts.